# Save SELECT query output to a text file with pipe delimter

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE 


--EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x'
```

now i am getting the result but it is not pipe delimter  I need to get the  result  with pipe as a delimter how can i get it  done

Thanks
Prince

Comment: answer: EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x -t"|"'

Comment: Please post this as another answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command-line `osql` command:

```
osql -S server -d database -E ^
  -Q "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" ^
  -s "|" -w 500 > c:\text.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the replay i solved it  by this way EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x -t"|"'

Comment: You may want to post this as another answer and accept it then, which is perfectly acceptable and will bring the question to a close.